# Для чего в Магическом квадрате Ло Шу проверка на уникальность значений списка

Tags: python

Код из книги. Программа имитирует магический квадрат Ло Шу. Все понятно кроме условия проверяемого функцией check_unique. Что значит значения в списке уникальные? В чем вообще смысл данной функции?

```
# Глобальные константы
ROWS = 3    # Количество строк
COLS = 3    # Количество столбцов
MIN = 1     # Значение наименьшего числа
MAX = 9     # Значение наибольшего числа

def main():
    # Создать двумерный список.
    test_list = [ [4, 9, 2],
                  [3, 5, 7],
                  [8, 1, 6] ]

    # Показать список в строковом и постолбцовом формате.
    display_square_list(test_list)
    
    # Определить, является ли список магическим квадратом Ло Шу.
    if is_magic_square(test_list):
        print('Это магический квадрат Ло Шу.')
    else:
        print('Это не магический квадрат Ло Шу.')

# Функция display_square_list принимает двумерный список   
# в качестве аргумента и показывает значения списка в строковом
# и постолбцовом формате.
def display_square_list(value_list):
    for r in range(ROWS):
        for c in range(COLS):
            print(value_list[r][c], end=' ')
        print()

# Функция is_magic_square принимает двумерный список
# в качестве аргумента и возвращает True, если список удовлетворяет
# всем требованиям, предъявляемым к магическому квадрату. 
# В противном случае она возвращает False.
def is_magic_square(value_list):
    # Исходно назначить состоянию значение False.
    status = False
    
    # Вызвать функции и сохранить возвращаемые из них значения.
    is_in_range = check_range(value_list)      # в диапазоне
    is_unique = check_unique(value_list)       # уникальные
    is_equal_rows = check_row_sum(value_list)  # равные строки
    is_equal_cols = check_col_sum(value_list)  # равные столбцы
    is_equal_diag = check_diag_sum(value_list) # равные диагонали

    # Определить, удовлетворяет ли список всем требованиям.
    if is_in_range and \
       is_unique and \
       is_equal_rows and \
       is_equal_cols and \
       is_equal_diag:
        
        # Если да, то назначить переменной status значение True.
        status = True

    # Вернуть status.
    return status

# Функция check_range принимает двумерный список
# в качестве аргумента и возвращает True, если значения
# в списке лежат в пределах указанного диапазона. 
# В противном случае она возвращает False.
def check_range(value_list):
    # Исходно назначить состоянию значение True.
    status = True

    # Перебрать все значения в списке.
    for r in range(ROWS):
        for c in range(COLS):
            # Определить, есть ли какие-либо значения,
            # которые лежат за пределами диапазона.
            if value_list[r][c] < MIN or \
               value_list[r][c] > MAX:
                # Если да, назначить status значение False.
                status = False
                
    # Вернуть status.
    return status

# Функция check_unique принимает двумерный список
# в качестве аргумента и возвращает True, если значения
# в списке уникальные. 
# В противном случае она возвращает False.
def check_unique(value_list):
    # Исходно назначить состоянию значение True.
    status = True
    # Инициализировать переменную искомым значением.
    search_value = MIN
    # Инициализировать счетчик нулем.
    count = 0

    # Выполнять поиск до тех пор, пока не будет достигнуто
    # минимальное значение и при этом значение являются
    # уникальными.
    while search_value <= MAX and status == True:
        # Перебрать все значения в списке.
        for r in range(ROWS):
            for c in range(COLS):
                # Определить, равняется ли текущее
                # значение искомому значению.
                if value_list[r][c] == search_value:
                    # Если да, нарастить счетчик.
                    count += 1
                # Определить, является ли счетчик
                # больше единицы.
                if count > 1:
                    # Если да, то значение не уникальное.
                    # Присвоить переменной status значение False.
                    status = False
        # Нарастить значение переменной search_value.
        search_value += 1
        # Обнулить переменную count.
        count = 0
        
    # Вернуть status.
    return status

# Функция check_row_sum принимает двумерный список
# в качестве аргумента и возвращает True, если сумма
# значений в каждой строке списка одинаковая.
# В противном случае она возвращает False.
def check_row_sum(value_list):
    # Исходно назначить состоянию значение True.
    status = True

    # Вычислить сумму значений в первой строке.
    sum_row_0 = value_list[0][0] + \
                value_list[0][1] + \
                value_list[0][2]

    # Вычислить сумму значений во второй строке.
    sum_row_1 = value_list[1][0] + \
                value_list[1][1] + \
                value_list[1][2]

    # Вычислить сумму значений в третьей строке.
    sum_row_2 = value_list[2][0] + \
                value_list[2][1] + \
                value_list[2][2]

    # Определить, не является ли сумма любой строки одинаковой.
    if (sum_row_0 != sum_row_1) or \
       (sum_row_0 != sum_row_2) or \
       (sum_row_1 != sum_row_2):
        # Если да, то присвоить переменной status значение False
        status = False

    # Вернуть status.
    return status

# Функция check_col_sum принимает двумерный список
# в качестве аргумента и возвращает True, если сумма
# значений в каждом столбце списка одинаковая.
# В противном случае она возвращает False.
def check_col_sum(value_list):
    # Исходно назначить состоянию значение True.
    status = True

    # Вычислить сумму значений в первом столбце.
    sum_col_0 = value_list[0][0] + \
                value_list[1][0] + \
                value_list[2][0]

    # Вычислить сумму значений во втором столбце.
    sum_col_1 = value_list[0][1] + \
                value_list[1][1] + \
                value_list[2][1]

    # Вычислить сумму значений в третьем столбце.
    sum_col_2 = value_list[0][2] + \
                value_list[1][2] + \
                value_list[2][2]

    # Определить, не является ли сумма любого столбца одинаковой
    if (sum_col_0 != sum_col_1) or \
       (sum_col_0 != sum_col_2) or \
       (sum_col_1 != sum_col_2):
        # Если да, то присвоить переменной status значение False
        status = False

    # Вернуть status.
    return status

# Функция check_diag_sum принимает двумерный список
# в качестве аргумента и возвращает True, если сумма
# значений в каждой диагонали списка одинаковая.
# В противном случае она возвращает False.
def check_diag_sum(value_list):
    # Исходно назначить состоянию значение True.
    status = True

    # Вычислить сумму значений в первой диагонали.
    sum_diag_0 = value_list[0][0] + \
                 value_list[1][1] + \
                 value_list[2][2]

    # Вычислить сумму значений во второй диагонали.
    sum_diag_1 = value_list[2][0] + \
                 value_list[1][1] + \
                 value_list[0][2]

    # Определить, не является ли сумма диагоналей одинаковой
    if sum_diag_0 != sum_diag_1:
        status = False

    # Вернуть status.
    return status

# Вызвать главную функцию.
main()
```

Comment: `check_unique` в двадцать раз длинее чем должна быть. Бегите!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы зададите список из девяти одинаковых значений (например, равных 5),  то будут выполняться все условия, кроме уникальности значений.

Уникальность означает, что числа не должны повторяться, все должны быть различны.

Comment: блин, элементарные вещи в голову не приходят. Спасибо.